# Unexpected query results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Why I get following results from sql-server?

```
SELECT '' + 12 C1, CONVERT(int, '') C2,
       CASE WHEN '' = ' ' THEN 'equal' ELSE 'not equal' END C3
```

[Sql-Server Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9429)

```
--Results
| C1 | C2 |    C3 |
-------------------
| 12 |  0 | equal |
```

**EDIT:** C3 has been answered. Everyone answered thinking `'' + 12 = 12` is string concatenation but it is a mathematical operation. It is not clear why (*NOT* how) `''` is converting to a 0 in sql-server.

Comment: Are you talking about `'' = ' '` (empty string compared with a single space)?

Comment: But since you have three different cases where you are using `''`, it was not clear whether you found the results of `'' + 12`, `CONVERT(int, '')` or `'' = ' '` to be unexpected. Two of those I would expect, one I wouldn't, but other may have other expectations. I was asking to clarify - only show the code that you are asking about - the extra stuff just obscures the issue.

Comment: @Oded: I tested myself if empty string convertible to an int, that is why c2 is there. one is implicit and one is explicit. Didn't mean to confuse.

Comment: I understand it was part of your test, but it shouldn't have been part of the question...

Comment: OK. It was not clear that all three were not expected... like I said, for me, two were.

Comment: These look like the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server has a strange feature whereby, if two strings are compared, and they are not of equal length, then it will pad the shorter one to the length of the longer one and then compare them. The padding character is a space. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

C1 & C2 are just implicit & explicit conversion of an empty string to 0.

Comment: Certain conversions work in certain ways on certain systems, and may not be exactly specified in the standard. For example, on Oracle, an empty string is considered NULL, which is how an empty string is considered in the C programming language. Where something is not specific in the standard, a vendor is free to implement as they choose.

Comment: An empty string is considered null in C? First time I've heard of that. Even if it is true - which I doubt - nulls in C are very different than `NULL` values in SQL.

Comment: It's common knowledge actually that a string in C is just an array of characters with a zero byte at the end. Hence, an empty string is just a zero byte, therefore equal to 0. NULL in C is #define'd to 0. I'm not disagreeing that C and SQL and different, just pointing out what Oracle does.

Comment: Well, you were referring to the null character (`\0`,  1 byte). I was thinking of the NULL pointer (which is usually 4 bytes).

Answer (score 9):

This is - more or less - expected behaviour. From a  copy of the SQL (ISO/ANSI) Standard:

> The comparison of two character string expressions depends on the collation used for the comparison. When values of unequal length are compared, if the collation for the comparison has the `NO PAD` characteristic and the shorter value is equal to some prefix of the longer value, then the shorter value is considered less than the longer value. If the collation for the comparison has the `PAD SPACE` characteristic, for the purposes of the comparison, ***the shorter value is effectively extended to the length of the longer by concatenation of <space>s on the right***.

Now, most DBMS have implemented string comparisons with slight differences. In SQL_Server and MySQL, you'll find that `''`, `' '`, `'  '` and `'   '` (strings with 0, 1, 2 and 3 spaces) are all equal, no matter if they are defined as `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`.

In Postges, they are all unequal if they are `VARCHAR` but equal if `CHAR` (so no padding in `VARCHAR` columns). If one of them is VARCHAR and one CHAR, then they are found equal, so I guess that padding is done before comparison.

Oracle is similar to Postgres with the extra peculiarity that the empty string `''` behaves (almost everywhere) as `NULL`. So, when you compare it to the strings with one or more spaces (or to itself), the result is neither True nor False but `UNKNOWN`. Oracle has one more difference, if one string is defined as `VARCHAR` and the other as `CHAR`, the comparison is rather complicated. From tests, I assume that only `CHAR` are padded in that case, up to their (defined datatype) length and then compared to the unpadded `VARCHAR`.

You can check (all 4 DBMS) in the **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad51e/1)**

Comment: Thanks, C3 results is clear but not sure why it is done that way. C1/C2 ?

Comment: It is other way around. `+`is *not* taking as `string concatenation` here. It is mathematical operator. Pls check this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9440).

Comment: @Kaf: You are right, my mistake. The situation is actually more complicated but you are right in this case.

Answer (score 4):

`C1` - An implicit conversion is happening here, the empty string gets converted to 0. This explains why you are getting `12` (`0 + 12).

`C2` - Explicitly converting `''` to an integer results in `0`. A bit artibrary, but that's how it works (and might change - as far as I know this is not documented, if anyone knows otherwise, please correct me).

`C3` - See [the answer by muhmud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055436/1583) - essentially when comparing strings of different lengths, the shorter one first gets padded with spaces to the length of the longer.