# Hibernate and PostgreSQL char type compatibility issue

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a Customers(one) <-> OrderRecords(many) relation in the database, and OrderRecords have foreign key to reference Customers' id.

`CREATE TABLE customers (cid VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));`

`CREATE TABLE orderrecords (order_id INT, customer_id VARCHAR(8), amount REAL, FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(cid));`

And the Hibernate codes are

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customers")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="cid")
    private String cid;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="orderRecordPK.customer")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<OrderRecord> orderRecords = new HashSet<OrderRecord>();

    ...
    other fields, getters and setters
}
```

OrderRecord.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OrderRecords")
public class OrderRecord implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderRecordPK orderRecordPK;

    ...
    other fields, getters and setters
}
```

OrderRecordPK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderRecordPK implements Serializable{
    @Column(name="order_id")
    private int orderId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", nullable=false)
    private Customer customer;

    ...
    other fields, getters and setters
}
```

The database is PostgreSQL. The problem is when the foreign key in OrderRecords table is type of varchar, every thing works fine. The generated HQL is
`Hibernate: select customer0_.cid as cid0_1_, customer0_.name as name0_1_, orderrecor1_.customer_id as customer3_0_3_, orderrecor1_.customer_id as customer3_3_, orderrecor1_.order_id as order1_3_, orderrecor1_.customer_id as customer3_2_0_, orderrecor1_.order_id as order1_2_0_, orderrecor1_.amount as amount2_0_ from Customers customer0_ left outer join OrderRecords orderrecor1_ on customer0_.cid=orderrecor1_.customer_id where customer0_.cid=?`

But if the foreign key in OrderRecords table is type of char, there will be no data returned for OrderRecords. The HQL will be
`Hibernate: select customer0_.cid as cid0_1_, customer0_.name as name0_1_, orderrecor1_.customer_id as customer3_0_3_, orderrecor1_.customer_id as customer3_3_, orderrecor1_.order_id as order1_3_, orderrecor1_.customer_id as customer3_2_0_, orderrecor1_.order_id as order1_2_0_, orderrecor1_.amount as amount2_0_ from Customers customer0_ left outer join OrderRecords orderrecor1_ on customer0_.cid=orderrecor1_.customer_id where customer0_.cid=?`

`Hibernate: select orderrecor0_.customer_id as customer3_0_1_, orderrecor0_.customer_id as customer3_1_, orderrecor0_.order_id as order1_1_, orderrecor0_.customer_id as customer3_2_0_, orderrecor0_.order_id as order1_2_0_, orderrecor0_.amount as amount2_0_ from OrderRecords orderrecor0_ where orderrecor0_.customer_id=?`

What is the proper way the fix the problem?

Comment: try mapping with `orderRecordPK.customer.cid`

Comment: I found a workaround. When sending the id for a query, and if the id's data type is char on the table, I will need to add space to fill up the char length defined on the table. For example, if the id on the table is char(8), the I will use `"1234[][][][]"`([] indicates space) for the query.

Comment: That is weird, I would have thought that the spaces would be before the actual id. I guess that is the way PostgreSQL handles it.

Comment: Why would that be of the type `char`? Does it **ALWAYS** have the **EXACTLY** same number of characters?

Comment: @MatheusOl, when you write SQL statement, or have one level mapping in Hibernate, it does not have to.

Comment: According the the SQL standard comparison rules, a shorter string (be it a char or varchar) would be padded with spaces when the server does the equality check. Either PostgreSQL doesn't follow the standard here, or the column is a binary, or has a collation which doesn't allow padding.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In Postgres, when doing string comparisons, there is no padding when both are VARCHAR columns, only when at least one is a CHAR. But the behaviour could be affected by settings, not sure. See this answer and the fiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055360/unexpected-query-results/15055727#15055727

Comment: Can you check your data (for both cases, when the datatypes are VARCHAR and CHAR) and whether there are leading and trailing spaces? The issue might be caused by the inserts (pushing spaces in the wrong places.)